# Plotting mean-values of elements with same frequencies

Tags: plot, google-sheets

I have two columns in my google sheet that corresponds to 1) the frequencies of the elements and 2) their respective 'values'.

What I want is a diagram that holds the different frequencies on the x-axis, and for each frequency I want the y-axis to hold that specific frequency's value (and if there are more than one element with that frequency I want it to plot their mean value).

Two elements can share the same frequency and/or the same score, and that's why I want the mean-functionality added aswell.

If the following data would be my values:

```
280    6
280    4
250    2
240    1
230    3
```

Forgive my ascii-skills, but I'd want the graph to plot the following in that case:

```
^
.
.
|
|                                 |
|                                 |
|   |                             |
|   |           |                 |
|   |     |     |                 |
___230___240___250___260___270___280___...>
```

I'm not entirely familiar with Google Sheets yet and I'm not really sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a pivot table should serve. Your LH column in Rows, RH in Values, with Summarise by AVERAGE. Then chart the results (select what in the image is B14:B17, Insert..., Chart  and accept the first recommendation):

[image: SO43590900 example]